# Visual studio 2012 cant compile a solution made with VS 2013

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

the title says it all, but let me elaborate.
I have a Visual studio 2013 at home, and whenever I create a code, copy it and take it to work where I open & compile it, it doesnt let me compile the file. When I try to do it the opposite way (open VS 2012 file in VS2013) it wants to update some librarys.

Anyway I hope this was understandable and I hope for any advices.

Thanks !

Comment: Sounds pretty normal to me...

Comment: Oh, so theres only "one-way" compatibility between VS2012 and VS2013 files ? (.sln)

Comment: @Raz it depends on the project type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is normal for certain types of projects.  MSDN has a [Project Compatibility page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747.aspx) which lists the project compatibility and round trip capabilities by project type.

For example, if you make a Windows Store app on 2013, it will automatically target Windows 8.1, which will only work on VS 2013, and not VS 2012.  However, a C# Windows Forms project will round trip with no issues.

Comment: Thanks for the reply !

One of the projects that dont work between these two versions is for example C++ console app. I needed that page. Thanks again :)